# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, timeout

I'm not sure if this is a VB.NET error or SQL Server.  But I get the above error with following stack trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout
>   expired.  The timeout period elapsed
>   prior to completion of the operation
>   or the server is not responding.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   +1950890    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   +4846875    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +194
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +2392
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
>   +33    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>   +83    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader
>   ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String
>   resetOptionsString) +297
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>   +954    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, String method,
>   DbAsyncResult result) +162
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, String method)
>   +32    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +141
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +12
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +10
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) +130
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet
>   dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32
>   maxRecords, String srcTable,
>   IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +287
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet
>   dataSet) +94
>   GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.GetComplaintTrendingList6(DateTime
>   FirstMonth, DateTime LastMonth, Int32
>   rowLevel) +489
>   ASP.website_complaints_complainttrendinglist6_aspx.Main()
>   in
>   e:\inetpub\amdmetrics-d.web.abbott.com\wwwroot\Website\Complaints\ComplaintTrendingList6.aspx:94
>   ASP.website_complaints_complainttrendinglist6_aspx.Page_Load(Object
>   Sender, EventArgs E) in
>   e:\inetpub\amdmetrics-d.web.abbott.com\wwwroot\Website\Complaints\ComplaintTrendingList6.aspx:60
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr
>   fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>   +14    System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +35
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +99
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +50    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

This is on Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3620; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618 and SQL Server 2008.
The line it flags causing this error says:

```
1: PrintMessageGrid.DataSource = GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.GetComplaintTrendingList6(FirstMonthDate, LastMonthDate, TheLevel)
```

Even though I can run this stored procedure in Query Analyzer and it returns in 8 seconds.  What could be the cause and fix?

Here's more detail where I declare this function:

```
Public Shared Function GetComplaintTrendingList6(ByVal FirstMonth As DateTime, ByVal LastMonth As DateTime, ByVal rowLevel As Integer) As DataSet
    Dim DSPageData As New System.Data.DataSet
    Dim param(2) As SqlClient.SqlParameter

    param(0) = New SqlParameter("@FirstMonthDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
    param(0).Value = FirstMonth
    param(1) = New SqlParameter("@LastMonthDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
    param(1).Value = LastMonth
    param(2) = New SqlParameter("@TheLevel", SqlDbType.Int)
    param(2).Value = rowLevel

    ''# A Using block will ensure the .Dispose() method is called for these variables, even if an exception is thrown 
    ''# This is IMPORTANT - not disposing your connections properly can result in an unrespsonsive database 
    Using conn As New SQLConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("AMDMetricsDevConnectionString")), _
   cmd As New SQLCommand("ComplaintTrendingList6", conn), _
    da As New SQLDataAdapter(cmd)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param)

        da.Fill(DSPageData)
    End Using

    Return DSPageData
End Function
```

The strange thing is that if I make this small change in my stored proc, it passes, but doesn't give me the data I want:
No error, but this version doesn't give me what I want:

```
SELECT E.PRODUCT_GROUP, a.QXP_SHORT_DESC, COUNT(DISTINCT A.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO), A.QXP_REPORT_DATE, DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, A.QXP_REPORT_DATE), 0) AS STARTDATE
FROM ALL_COMPLAINTS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ISSUE_REF D ON A.QXP_ID = D.IRF_QXP_ID 
INNER JOIN CT_ProductFailures b ON b.old_modes = a.qxp_short_desc
LEFT OUTER JOIN [MANUAL].PRODUCTS E ON A.EPA_PRD_CODE = E.LIST_NUMBER 
LEFT JOIN SMARTSOLVE.V_CXP_CUSTOMER_PXP C ON A.QXP_ID = C.QXP_ID
INNER JOIN @SelectedLevels F ON A.[LEVEL] = F.LevelId
WHERE   --[LEVEL] > 0 AND
(A.QXP_SHORT_DESC <> 'Design Control') 
and A.QXP_REPORT_DATE >= @OneYearAgo AND A.QXP_REPORT_DATE <= @LastMonthDate
AND (C.QXP_EXCEPTION_TYPE <> 'Non-Diagnostic' OR C.QXP_EXCEPTION_TYPE IS NULL)  
GROUP BY E.PRODUCT_GROUP, A.QXP_REPORT_DATE,  A.QXP_SHORT_DESC
```

Error-causing stored proc:

```
INSERT #PVAL_NUM
SELECT E.PRODUCT_GROUP, b.new_modes 'QXP_SHORT_DESC', COUNT(DISTINCT A.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO), A.QXP_REPORT_DATE, DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, A.QXP_REPORT_DATE), 0) AS STARTDATE
FROM ALL_COMPLAINTS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ISSUE_REF D ON A.QXP_ID = D.IRF_QXP_ID 
INNER JOIN CT_ProductFailures b ON b.old_modes = a.qxp_short_desc
LEFT OUTER JOIN [MANUAL].PRODUCTS E ON A.EPA_PRD_CODE = E.LIST_NUMBER 
LEFT JOIN SMARTSOLVE.V_CXP_CUSTOMER_PXP C ON A.QXP_ID = C.QXP_ID
INNER JOIN @SelectedLevels F ON A.[LEVEL] = F.LevelId
WHERE   --[LEVEL] > 0 AND
(A.QXP_SHORT_DESC <> 'Design Control') 
and A.QXP_REPORT_DATE >= @OneYearAgo AND A.QXP_REPORT_DATE <= @LastMonthDate
AND (C.QXP_EXCEPTION_TYPE <> 'Non-Diagnostic' OR C.QXP_EXCEPTION_TYPE IS NULL)
GROUP BY E.PRODUCT_GROUP, A.QXP_REPORT_DATE, b.new_modes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get with the Query Analyzer (or SSMS, these days) and what you application gets can be very different things, mostly due to parameter sniffing.

I suggest reading [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) by Erland Sommarskog for a details.

Answer (score 9):

You need to increase the command timeout on the select command of the dataadapter.

Below is the code to increase the command timeout for dataadapter.

```
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

SQL Connection timeout is different from timeout set for the Command that is executed.

It is defined as follows. 
From MSDN

> Gets the time to wait while trying to establish a connection before
>   terminating the attempt and generating an error.

On setting the connection timeout.. from MSDN

> You can set the amount of time a connection waits to time out by using
>   the ConnectTimeout or Connection Timeout keywords in the connection
>   string. A value of 0 indicates no limit, and should be avoided in a
>   ConnectionString because an attempt to connect waits indefinitely.

Default value for all timeouts is 30 secs.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that means the database operation took too long and it gave up.

Try adding a Connect Timeout in the web.config

```
<add key="DBConnection" value="server=LocalHost;uid=sa;pwd=;database=DataBaseName;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200"/>
```

Comment: Rob, if this stored proc only took 8 seconds to run in QA, do u think it would time out with default timeout settings?

Answer (score -1):

> *"..database operation took too long and it gave up."*

This is correct.  This happens when there's a conflict with your connection to the server.

To temporarily resolve this..

"Repair your LAN connection"

You can do this by right-clicking on your connection and clicking "REPAIR"

To permanently resolve this..

There shouldn't be a combination of static and dynamic ip addresses in your workgroup.  If you want to set a static group, do not include dynamic connections - vice versa.

After that, there shouldn't be an error displaying "Timeout Expired" anymore.

cheers!